# Regex to match a specific sequence of strings

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Assuming I have 2 array of strings 
position1 = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
position2 = ['word4', 'word1']

and I want inside a text/string to check if the substring #{target} which exists in text is followed by either one of the words of *position1* or following one of the words of the *position2* or even both at the same time. Similarly as if I am looking left and right of #{target}.

For example in the sentence "Writing reports and inputting **data** onto internal systems, with regards to enforcement and immigration papers" if the target word is **data** I would like to check if the word left (inputting) and right (onto) are included in the arrays or if one of the words in the arrays return true for the regex match. Any suggestions? I am using Ruby and I have tried some regex but I can't make it work yet. I also have to ignore any potential special characters in between.

One of them:

```
/^.*\b(#{joined_position1})\b.*$[\s,.:-_]*\b#{target}\b[\s,.:-_\\\/]*^.*\b(#{joined_position2})\b.*$/i
```

Edit:

I figured out this way with regex to capture the word left and right:

```
(\S+)\s*#{target}\s*(\S+)
```

However what could I change if I would like to capture more than one words left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two arrays of strings, what you can do is something like this:

```
matches = /^.+ (\S+) #{target} (\S+) .+$/.match(text)
if matches and (position1.include?(matches[1]) or position2.include?(matches[2]))
    do_something()
end
```

What this regex does is match the target word in your text and extract the words next to it using capture groups. The code then compares those words against your arrays, and does something if they're in the right places. A more general version of this might look like:

```
def checkWords(target, text, leftArray, rightArray, numLeft = 1, numRight = 1)
    # Build the regex
    regex = "^.+"
    regex += " (\S+)" * numLeft
    regex += " #{target}"
    regex += " (\S+)" * numRight
    regex += " .+$"

    pattern = Regexp.new(regex)
    matches = pattern.match(text)

    return false if !matches

    for i in 1..numLeft
        return false if (!leftArray.include?(matches[i]))
    end

    for i in 1..numRight
        return false if (!rightArray.include?(matches[numLeft + i]))
    end

    return true
end
```

Which can then be invoked like this:

```
do_something() if checkWords("data", text, position1, position2, 2, 2)
```

I'm pretty sure it's not terribly idiomatic, but it gives you a general sense of how you would do what you in a more general way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand why it throws a NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for matches although matches should exist in the text

Comment: I updated it not to crash if your target text isn't found.

Comment: Thank you. Could it be possible to include 2 or more neighboring words instead of one with regex?

Comment: Anyway I can just repeat the (.+) but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way

Comment: @Vas: I added a more general version that'll do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. However the regex seems to cause Catastrophic backtracking

Comment: ^.+ (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) £24,336 (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) .+$ etc seens to work better